# VSCode dynamic environment variables for remote debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I have a C++ debug `launch.json` configuration that works fine for local debugging because VSCode picks up the local environment and everything runs fine:

```
{
    "name": "Linux GDB Test",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/testsuite/bin/${env:OSNAME}/${env:OSARCH}/testrunnerd",
    "args": ["-all"],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "externalConsole": false,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "setupCommands": [
      {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
      }
      ]
  }
```

But this does not work for debugging sessions on the remote host. So I added a task that writes the environment to a file and modify the debug configuration accordingly to read it from the file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "OSENV",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "printf \"OSNAME=`uname -s`\nOSARCH=`uname -m`\n\" > ${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": false,
                "reveal": "never",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": false,
                "clear": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Add `preLaunchTask` and `envFile` to the debug configuration:

```
{
    "name": "Linux GDB Test",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "preLaunchTask": "OSENV",
    "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/testsuite/bin/${env:OSNAME}/${env:OSARCH}/testrunnerd",
    "args": ["-all"],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "externalConsole": false,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "setupCommands": [
      {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
      }
      ]
  }
```

The file is created:

```
$ cat .env 
OSNAME=Linux
OSARCH=x86_64
```

but the debugger does not see it:

```
launch: program '.../testsuite/bin///testrunnerd' does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to to dynamically set environment for remote debugging session?